# Disregarding first part of split string

Tags: java, string

If I have a string like : **1234_my_string.txt** is there a better way than the one provided to lop off the **1234_** so the value of the string would be equal to **my_string.txt**?  
To be clear, I want to discard everything up to and including the first '_' in the string. The string is not neccessarily equal to "1234_my_string.txt". The length of the characters before the first '_' is not known.

Pseudocode:

```
String str = "1234_my_string.txt";
do foo
str == my_string.txt
```

Here is a working example I currently have which checks the value of str then splits and rejoins the string to get the desired result. The size of characters I want to lop off is not known. I do not think this is very efficient:

```
        if(str != null && !str.equals("") )
        {
            String [] strParts = str.split("_");
            val = "";

            for (int i = 1; i < strParts.length; i++)
            {
                str += strParts[i];
                str += "_";
            }

            str = str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
        }
```

Comment: For clarification, you have String str = "1234_my_string.txt" and you are looking to discard the "1234"?

Comment: If you know the amount of characters you want to split off, you could use [the substring()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm) method.  If it is not constant, you could do a split and check the length of the first array and go from there.

Comment: @ryekayo I am looking to discard the "1234_"

Comment: @Childishforlife I do not know the amount of characters to split off

Comment: @Turtle, you just contradicted yourself.

Comment: @shmosel how did I contradict myself?

Comment: Do you want to remove only `[number]_` part which was at start, or any `[anyString]_` which is placed at start?

Comment: @Pshemo just updated the answer to hopefully make it more clear. The `[number]_`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to get rid of everything up to and including the first `_`, one easy way would just be to use a regular expression and replace that section with `""`.

e.g.

```
String str = "1234_my_string.txt";
str = str.replaceFirst("[^_]*_", "");
System.out.println(str);  // my_string.txt
```

Comment: How about `replaceFirst(".*?_", "")`?

Comment: @shmosel `[^_]*` is more efficient than `.*?` since it avoids backtracking.

Answer (score 7):

Probably simplest solution would be

```
str = str.substring(str.indexOf('_') + 1);
```

If you are sure that your string will contain at least one `_` you can also use something like:

```
str = str.split("_", 2)[1];
//        splits max into two parts
//        [1] get second part (the one after "_")
```

Comment: *If you are sure that your string will contain at least one `_`* If you're not, the first solution will throw an exception.

Comment: shmosel @Turtle Fixed.